# Adding a string to a session variable echo

Tags: php, html, string, variables, session

Sorry, struggling to find this on here, probably because its really simple. Just want to add a string to this code. Such as "Welcome: +$SESSION".

New to PHP dont really know how to add the extra line within this code.

`<label class="welcome"><?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['u_username'])){echo $_SESSION['u_username'];}?></label>`

Comment: what do you mean by "add the extra line within this code?" what extra line?

Comment: What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to add to the strings. In " " quotes directly, if using arrays etc within it then you have to remove quotes from the array key,

```
<label class="welcome"><?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['u_username'])){echo " Welcome $_SESSION[u_username]";}?></label>
```

OR adding it with .

```
<label class="welcome"><?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['u_username'])){echo "Welcome " .$_SESSION['u_username'];}?></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the two strings:

1) `Welcome`

2) `$_SESSION['u_username']`

You can do it by using `.` operator.

Unlike Java or JavaScript, PHP uses `.` for concatenation instead of `+`

So, your final code should be:

```
<label class="welcome">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['u_username'])) {
 echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['u_username'];
}
?>
</label>
```